# database migrated with talend big data but there is a jump on id

Tags: talend

I have created a job that migrate data from mongodb to mysql, all data are passed even it showed on tlogrow but when i check my new tale on mysql, i can't find 3 rows, even id is jumping from 57 to 59 and from 79 to 81 and from 83 to 85.
from 92 rows i found 89 anth the 3 others are hidden or i don't know
why ?
[image]
[image]

anyone can help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing my schemas, i fount that there is a duplicated key on 3 records.